# Pubnub History Api

Tags: python-2.7, pubnub

I am trying to extract the message from my pubnub history, where I wish to compare any change of messages. For the same I am calling pubnub.history in my main callback function (used by pubnub.subscribe) -

pubnub.history(channel=channel, count = 1, callback =_callback,error=_error)

and I define my _callback as:

```
def _callback(message):
    _type = message[0]
    _type_ = _type[0]
    prevMess = _type_['command']

    if prevMess == "..":
        flag = 1

    elif prevMess == "...":
        flag = 4

    elif prevMess == "....":
        flag = 7

    print flag
```

How can I successfully 'return' the flag value from the _callback() to my callback()? Or in that case return "prevMess" value from _callback() to callback()?

Comment: You can double up on your callbacks to make a **"wrapper"** callback.  That way you can call your own "History" method, and it returns the data format you seek.

Comment: I am not seeing where you define `callback`. I only see `_callback` so it is difficult to recommend a solution. But the PubNub API callbacks are invoked asynchronously and not invoked directly by your code so not sure what you mean by having `_callback` call `callback`. I think we just need more code for full context of your issues.